# Android dynamic icon in listview

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity in my application.  The list is populated from a parsed http response in the form of an ArrayList of hashmaps.

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
...
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, LIST, R.layout.item_row, new String[]{"author","title"}, new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2});
setListAdapter(adapter);
...
for(Element src : lists){
     String title = src.select();
     String author = src.select();
     HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
     temp.put("author", author);
     temp.put("title", title);
     LIST.add(temp);
}
```

Where author and title are correctly derived from the parsed http.

In the R.layout.item_row XML file I have defined a drawable for text2:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/default_icon"
```

And i would like to be able to change that icon to "new_icon" on a given row if the hashmap contains a certain string.

For instance, within the for loop above, I would add something like:

```
String status = src.select();
String icon = "default";
if(status.contains("test")){
     icon = "should_change";
}
temp.put("icon", icon);
...etc
```

I'm leaving out the specific logic for brevity, but I am able to correctly pass whether the icon should change or not as a string value back to the adapter, however, I am not sure how to then actually change the icon.

I am not experienced with either Java or Android so I am quite likely approaching this backwards.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

First, instead of using SimpleAdapter, I added a class that extends SimpleAdapter

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

        public SpecialAdapter(Context context,
                List> data, int resource,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
}
```

and added into it a getView method that checks the value of "icon" and sets the drawable accordingly:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

             View row = convertView;

              if(row==null){
               LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
               row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
              }
              TextView text1=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
              text1.setText(LIST.get(position).get("author"));
              TextView text2=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
              text2.setText(LIST.get(position).get("title"));

              ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
              if(LIST.get(position).get("icon") == "should_change"){
                  icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_icon);  
              }
              else {
                  icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_icon);
              }



            return row;
        }
```

Then within my main class, I replaced the SimpleAdapter instance with SpecialAdapter.

And finally, in item_row.xml, I removed the drawableLeft definition, and added an ImageView with id of "icon" in its place

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! LIST didnt work for me - I had to make it the activity class that called the list, like MyActivity.LIST - Also shortend up with a define for details

```
HashMap<String, String> details = MyActivity.LIST.get(position);
TextView text1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text1.setText(details.get("author"));
```